# Eclipse not runing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 14.04 with oracle JRE JDK installed when trying to run Eclipse I get the following error

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/stamatisvergos/Desktop/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/stamatisvergos/Desktop/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.2.v20140221-1700/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/stamatisvergos/Desktop/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/stamatisvergos/Desktop/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212/eclipse_1508.so
-startup /home/stamatisvergos/Desktop/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 1bb8017
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/stamatisvergos/Desktop/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

pls help

Comment: This is a 32 bit Eclipse, are you running a 32 bit Java?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your are running a 32bit Eclipse only with a 32bit Java JRE installed. and a 64bit Eclipse only with a 64bit Java JRE installed.

Don't try to run a 32bit Eclipse version with a 64bit Java JRE. This will crash in an error like you get(also the other way around will not run).